# Почему Event Loop пропускает очередь poll и сразу выполняет check?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Почему Event Loop пропускает очередь poll и сразу выполняет check? Это же не логично все очереди он выполняет по порядку, а потом бац и перескакивает. Вот зачем и для чего не понятно.

Например вот в таком коде он сначала пойдет и выполнит setImmidiate вместо readFile

```
console.log('START');
 
setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout'), 0); //Попал в очередь timers 1)timers  set intervals  
setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate')); //Попал в очередь check 7


fs.readFile( 'eventloop.txt', () => { //попал в очередь poll
    setTimeout(() => console.log('readfile setTimeout'), 0);
    setImmediate(() => console.log('readFile setImmidiate'));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log('read file Next Tick'));
    }
)

Promise.resolve() // Попал в очередь other microtask que
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Promise')
                process.nextTick(() => console.log('Promise Next Tick'));
            })
            
            process.nextTick(() => console.log('nextTick'));
     
         setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout 2'), 0); //Попал в очередь timers 1)timers  set intervals  все node.js пропарсилась;
console.log('end')
```

|  | Как есть | Как ожидалось |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | START | START |
|  | end | end |
|  | nextTick | nextTick |
|  | Promise | Promise |
|  | Promise Next Tick | Promise Next Tick |
|  | setTimeout | setTimeout |
|  | setTimeout 2 | setTimeout 2 |
| → | setImmediate | read file Next Tick |
| → | read file Next Tick | readFile setImmidiate |
| → | readFile setImmidiate | readfile setTimeout |
| → | readfile setTimeout | setImmediate |

Comment: что за очередь poll, что за очередь check? Откуда эта терминология?

Comment: Терминология, видимо, отсюда: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, обращение к файловой системе Node.js делегирует системным вызовам, то есть эта фаза не полностью под контролем Node.js, в отличие от всех остальных в вашем скрипте. Поэтому, до тех пор, пока придёт ответ от файловой системы, event loop может пройти виток или больше.

> If the poll queue is empty, one of two more things will happen:
>
> - If scripts have been scheduled by setImmediate(), the event loop will end the poll phase and continue to the check phase to execute those scheduled scripts.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll